# How to use cell value for reference in query function?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query

I have google sheet with table name in row A

How can I use this name in QUERY function for reference rows?

For example if table name is "MyTable" I can use QUERY("MyTable"!A:"MyTable"!B) but how to read table name from cell?

Answer (score 0):

try like this:

```
=QUERY(INDIRECT(A1&"!A:B"))
```

where A1 is `MyTable` (eg. sheet name)